# Whonix over Qubes, Mac Address Error

Tags: whonix, qubes

When I try to run my whonix-gw on Qubes I get an error saying,"This MAC address already exists." Everything installed alright, and I followed the installation directions exactly.

Comment: Perhaps better suited for https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/qubes-users. Most likely a Qubes, not Tor issue. You'll need to write a more comprehensive report, though. Where and how this error popped up. I would speculate in dom0 by Qubes VM Manager.

Comment: yep, you nailed it.  VM won't start cussa this error.Thanks for the link, if you wanna make this the answer I'll give ya an upvote.

Comment: https://www.whonix.org/forum/index.php/topic,1784.0.html